# Input string was not in a correct format WHILE download specfic file from grid view

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

when i select user id from dropdown list .the files of that user are displayed in grid view but when i click on download button in gridview it give the error . Input string was not in a correct format for line for

```
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value);
```

Comment: what is index here? can u post the method?

Comment: string fileName = string.Empty;
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value);

Answer (score 0):

well try below code and implement in this way

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) 
    {
      if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      { 
           int productID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value); 
      }
   }
```